# how can i remove the auto-shutdown feature that is caused by overheating?

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard, shutdown, overheating

i'd like to remove all the safety features added by manufacturers that shutdown the laptop, i'm using a toshiba l755. note that i did several stress tests and pc worked fine and it had no thermal problems over a prolonged duration. i noted that the problem came from the sudden rise of the cpu's temperature while starting a game and thus it caused a shutdown, if for example the pc would be under load and then i start a game it would work fine but i'd like to find a permanent solution and not just a backdoor. the auto shutdown feature is useless in my case, and i'd love if anyone would provide a sort of guide or clearance on how i so such procedure whether it is hardware or software related. note that i have taken off all the plastic that covers the motherboard for maximum airflow so please do not worry about overheating. i would love to see a solution that works and to be honest i don't mind seeing this laptop burn tho it will never happen sadly even if i stop it from shutting down.

Comment: You can't. It's built in to the CPU. "When processor core temperature reaches a factory preset level, the sensor trips and processor execution is halted until after the next reset cycle.

The mechanism is builtin to the processor, not under the control of BIOS and not dependent on other sensor outside the processor."

Comment: The internal plastic baffling may have been designed to direct cooling to the CPU; removing it is unlikely to help. Try an external fan, preferably *not* powered from the USB port.

Comment: ty vm for the answers, at least i can stop looking aimlessly. i should just get a new pc i guess, this one has reached its limits. note that if you use the laptop without it's cover and expose the motherboard, it decreases the heat drastically and can limit the shutdowns to some extent, note that your motherboard will be exposed and might get damaged, so do that with caution if you intend to do that.